# Distinguish between similar values based on placement regex

Tags: javascript, css, regex

Here is my problem: I am working on a series of regex to dissect the shorthand css code of the font property. Here is what I have so far:

```
var style = decl.val.match(/\s*(?:\s*(normal|italic|oblique)){1}/i); style = style ? style[1] : "";
var variant = decl.val.match(/\s*(?:\s*(normal|small-caps))/i); variant = variant ? variant[1] : "";
var weight = decl.val.match(/\s*((?:\s*(?:normal|bold|bolder|lighter|\d+(?:\%|in|cm|mm|em|rem|ex|pt|pc|px))){1})/i); weight = weight ? weight[1] : "";
var size = decl.val.match(/\/\s*((?:\s*(?:xx-small|x-small|small|medium|large|x-large|xx-large|larger|smaller|\d+(?:\%|in|cm|mm|em|rem|ex|pt|pc|px))){1,2})/i); size = size ? size[1] : "";
var height = decl.val.match(/\s*(?:\s*(normal|inherit|\d+(?:\%|in|cm|mm|em|rem|ex|pt|pc|px))){1}/i); height = height ? height[1] : "";
var family = decl.val.match(/\s*(?:\s*([a-zA-Z\-\,\'\"\s]+))(?:,|;)/i); family = family ? family[1] : "";
var values = decl.val.match(/\s*(?:\s*(caption|icon|menu|message-box|small-caption|status-bar)){1}/i); values = values ? values[1] : "";
```

Everything works the way I want it to except when I try using the following string:

```
font: normal small-caps 120%/120% fantasy, sans-serif;
```

This causes the values of style, variant, weight, and height to all be set to normal:

```
style --> "normal"
variant --> "normal"
weight --> "normal"
height --> "normal"
```

This is because of the regex matches the first instance in each case and does not check to make sure that there is not some other value it is supposed to take. It should be:

```
style --> "normal"
variant --> "small-caps"
weight --> "120%"
height -->
```

I hope this makes sense. If you have any questions, please feel free to comment. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is this `\/\s*((?:` extra forward slash in the size's, a typo?

Comment: Are any fields optional ?

Comment: @sln Yes, I think the extra forward slash might be a typo... I was copying and pasting... Also all the fields are optional.

Answer (score 2):

There is a little problem of forward slash between weight and sizes.
But you would be better off combining into one regex making everything but
anchors optional.  This will line things up and you won't end up with 'normal'
on most of the vars.

**Edit**  According to this reference http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp
This is how they parse a CSS Font Shorthand Property.

**edit2**  Adjusted the hard space delimiters to be after the optional parts and between the required parts.

```
 #  /(?:(?:(normal|italic|oblique|initial|inherit)\s+)?(?:(normal|small-caps|initial|inherit)\s+)?(?:((?:normal|bold|bolder|lighter|initial|inherit|\d+))\s+)?(?:(smaller|small|x-small|xx-small|medium|larger|large|x-large|xx-large|initial|inherit|\d+(?:\%|in|cm|mm|em|rem|ex|pt|pc|px))(?:\/(normal|initial|inherit|\d+(?:\%|in|cm|mm|em|rem|ex|pt|pc|px)))?\s+)(?:(initial|inherit|(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[a-zA-Z-]+)(?:\s*,\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[a-zA-Z-]+))*))|(caption|icon|menu|message-box|small-caption|status-bar|initial|inherit))/

 ####  CSS - Font Shorthand Property  
 ####  Reference:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp    
 #### --------------------------------
 #### font:     

 (?:
      #### User Defined Fonts
      #### ------------------

      ##### Style (optional)
      (?:
           (                        # (1 start), Style
                normal
             |  italic
             |  oblique
             |  initial
             |  inherit 
           )                        # (1 end)
           \s+   # delimiter
      )?

      ##### Variant (optional)
      (?:
           (                        # (2 start), Variant
                normal
             |  small-caps
             |  initial
             |  inherit 
           )                        # (2 end)
           \s+   # delimiter
      )?

      ##### Weight (optional)
      (?:
           (                        # (3 start), Weight
                (?:
                     normal
                  |  bold
                  |  bolder
                  |  lighter
                  |  initial
                  |  inherit 
                  |  \d+ 
                )
           )                        # (3 end)
           \s+   # delimiter
      )?

      ##### Size (required)
      (?:
           (                        # (4 start), Size
                smaller
             |  small
             |  x-small
             |  xx-small
             |  medium
             |  larger
             |  large
             |  x-large
             |  xx-large
             |  initial
             |  inherit
             |  \d+ 
                (?: \% | in | cm | mm | em | rem | ex | pt | pc | px )
           )                        # (4 end)

           #####  Line Height (optional)
           (?:
                /                   # Separator
                (                   # (5 start), Line height
                     normal
                  |  initial
                  |  inherit
                  |  \d+ 
                     (?: \% | in | cm | mm | em | rem | ex | pt | pc | px )
                )                   # (5 end)

           )?

           \s+   # delimiter 
      )

      ##### Family (required)
      (?:
           (                        # (6 start), Family
                initial
             |  inherit
             |  (?: " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' | [a-zA-Z-]+ )
                (?:
                     \s* , \s* 
                     (?: " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' | [a-zA-Z-]+ )
                )*
           )                        # (6 end)
      )

   |  

      #### OR, 
      #### Use the Fonts used by these OS elements
      #### ------------------

      #### Values (required, if used)
      (                             # (7 start), Use values
           caption
        |  icon
        |  menu
        |  message-box
        |  small-caption
        |  status-bar
        |  initial
        |  inherit
      )                             # (7 end)
 )
```

Perl Test case

```
$str = 'font:normal small-caps 120%/120% "Times New Roman", sans-serif;';

if ( $str =~ /(?:(?:(normal|italic|oblique|initial|inherit)\s+)?(?:(normal|small-caps|initial|inherit)\s+)?(?:((?:normal|bold|bolder|lighter|initial|inherit|\d+))\s+)?(?:(smaller|small|x-small|xx-small|medium|larger|large|x-large|xx-large|initial|inherit|\d+(?:\%|in|cm|mm|em|rem|ex|pt|pc|px))(?:\/(normal|initial|inherit|\d+(?:\%|in|cm|mm|em|rem|ex|pt|pc|px)))?\s+)(?:(initial|inherit|(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[a-zA-Z-]+)(?:\s*,\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[a-zA-Z-]+))*))|(caption|icon|menu|message-box|small-caption|status-bar|initial|inherit))/)
{
    print "\nmatched  '$&'\n\n";
    print "style   = '$1'\n";
    print "variant = '$2'\n";
    print "weight  = '$3'\n";
    print "size    = '$4'\n";
    print "height  = '$5'\n";
    print "family  = '$6'\n";
    print "values  = '$7'\n";
}
```

Output >>

```
matched  'normal small-caps 120%/120% "Times New Roman", sans-serif'

style   = 'normal'
variant = 'small-caps'
weight  = ''
size    = '120%'
height  = '120%'
family  = '"Times New Roman", sans-serif'
values  = ''
```

Comment: Would this work with javascript too? Also, what happens when the line does not end with a semicolon?

Comment: Is there any way to place hold for an empty value? Like you did with pearl?

Comment: @Leinardo Smtih - Sorry I wasn't here when you posted these comments. First, I updated my answer to show how a browser would parse the font shortcut properties. I used this reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp). The compressed regex at the top of the formmated section, will work with JS. And, the number of capture groups are fixed at 7. They are all placeholders. This type of parse is mostly disambiguous. The only required fields are `Size` and `Family`, which is enough to line up the rest of the fields. Cheers!

Comment: It works great! The only thing I had to change was to remove the font: and change the first \s+ to \s* because some people don't put a space after their colon. Would these cause any conflicts?

Comment: @LeinardoSmtih - Yeah, you can't do that. I added a **edit2** that resolves that conflict. Essentially, a space delimiter _IS_ required between optional parts at the beginning and required parts at the end. The solution is to add `\s+` at the end of but _within_ the optional group, since in order for optional groups to match, they must be followed by the required 'Size' and 'Family'. These are the rules they use to parse the line.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is the following:

When you have found one attribute, remove this attribute from the string. Then search for the next attribute in the modified string.

This is an example for the first attribute in the string:

```
var str = decl.val;

function removeFromString(str, result) {
    console.log(result);
    return str.slice(0, result.index) + str.slice(result.index + result[0].length);
}

var style = str.match(/\s*(?:\s*(normal|italic|oblique)){1}/i); 
if(style) {
    str = removeFromString(str, style);
}
style = style ? style[1] : "";
```

I've made an **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byz9M/)** for this.